# Braintree client Token genaration from java api gives Exception

Tags: javascript, java, braintree

I am using braintree java api version 2.48.0 for with the v2 javascript. In order to create a drop in from i need to create client token. But whenever i am requesting for a client token i am getting AuthorizationException.

Code:

```
private static BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway(
  Environment.SANDBOX,
  "merchant_id",
  "public_key",
  "private_key");

public static String getToken() {
    String token = gateway.clientToken().generate(); // This line throws exception. 
    System.out.println("[DEBUG] Genareted Token " + token);
    return token;
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.braintreegateway.exceptions.AuthorizationException
at com.braintreegateway.util.Http.throwExceptionIfErrorStatusCode(Http.java:191)
at com.braintreegateway.util.Http.httpRequest(Http.java:89)
at com.braintreegateway.util.Http.post(Http.java:51)
at com.braintreegateway.ClientTokenGateway.generate(ClientTokenGateway.java:37)
at com.braintreegateway.ClientTokenGateway.generate(ClientTokenGateway.java:31)
at com.tigerworks.payment.BraintreeService.getToken(BraintreeService.java:20)
at com.tigerworks.payment.Program.main(Program.java:14)
```

How i can overcome this? where is the problem.

NB: The braintree object creation is provided by braintree control panel. so there is no posibality that is wrong. Though i am registerd under my official team.

Comment: Could you include comment after lines to determine the one which throws an exception?

Comment: If you got the answer mention it.

Answer (score 1):

I work as a developer at Braintree. You are seeing an `AuthorizationException` because you need to replace the `merchant_id`, `public_key`, and `private_key` values with your credentials. Navigate to "Setting" > "Users and Roles" in your Sandbox Control Panel. Go into your user page and click on "API Keys" to manage your API Keys. Click on the one you want to use and you will find these values listed there.

Comment: Hello @Kathryn, I used my original credentials on my code. I just removed them from here for security purpose. :) Probably i am getting an error because of my account is under an company account and i don't have access to all to the merchant id. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's good! No credentials produces that same error, so I just had to double check. :) You can always reach out to support at support@braintreepayments.com if you need any help with your account.

Comment: thanks kathryn. Solved the issue. The problem is i was under an organization account. And i did not granted permission. But on my account there is no way that i can know i do not have permission. my tokens get generated but they got AuthZ error. When i find this out. I ask for permission and then my credentials got working. You should have late a way to inform me that i need permissions. :)